# Showing characters while typing

Tags: javascript

I need to see characters while I am typing characters inside an input, and I want to achieve this the simplest way. I have tried the following way, but it is not working. I am more interested to know what I am doing wrong rather than to get a script.

```
<input type='text' id='inpt' />

<script>   
    var getText = document.getElementById("inpt");
    document.write(getText);   
</script>
```

Comment: See characters while typing in an input?  That is the default behavior.  Can you elaborate a bit?  You want a callback to be ran as people type?

Comment: Learn about the evenets keypress/keyup and learn about innerHTML

Comment: @Brad I mean, I need to see it outside, the input button, just like in SE when you  the are writting a querstion, you see it below input

Comment: As to what you're doing wrong: the script runs once, and that's it. You can't expect it to automatically run again every time you're typing on the input field.

Comment: @Juhana Oh, never knew about that. I thought, since Js runs in a browser, it would not need to send and recieve anything like PHP, anyway, how can I achive this

Comment: You do not have to send or receive,  but your code need to be triggered. Tats what events a good for. In your case the "onkeyup" event of the input will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of a callback, or event handler. Typically you would use `onkeyup=callback_name()`, and `callback_name()` would write to the element you want the output to appear in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function callback()
    {
      var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text;
    } 
</script>

<input type='text' id='input' onkeyup='callback()' />

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: No, I need the input to remain when you are typing.

Comment: That's the general idea, but `document.write()` will overwrite the entire page when used.

Comment: Still nothing, just a regular typing script

Comment: Yes, thanks. this is what I wanted. Can you give me a link to a good Js tutorial about manipulating texts

Comment: What does `).value;` mean btw

Comment: @kranzdot it's just accessing the `value` property of the element returned by `getElementById()`